# Duplicate check box in Javascript, not working with a class

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

A work in progress personal project that allows you to generate colour palettes based on an input, such as 'Black' or '#000000.

Problem is, when typing in a hex, such as '#000000', I have included a checkbox (using an id), this results in the checkbox only working for the first palette. However, when I change this to id="test1" it breaks it and I can't figure out why.

This is the checkbox I'm using:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="test1" /> <label for="test1"></label>
```

Can anyone help me figure out how to fix it so that all check boxes are clickable?

This is the live [link](http://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00553636/mpwip/app.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` attribute looks for the elements ID, not a class.

Zeh docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: So is this not possible to get the checkboxes to work for more than one palette, seeing it only looks for the ID and not a class?